# Custom alert dialog using DialogFragment is not behaving as expected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to implement a custom alert builder which should show a custom layout that I want to use. I have created a class named "AlertDialogClass" which extends DialogFragment. I am trying to show this alert builder class from a fragment.

I am not getting any error or any crash when using that AlertDialogClass but that layout which supposed to be shown is showing white screen only. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. I can't understand why it is happening or what I am doing wrong.

Here is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/backgroundElevation2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding18dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Connection Not Available !!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CardTextView"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please Check Your Internet Connection And Try Again"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CardTextViewSmall"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin3dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_connection"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background1"
            android:text="Try Again"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CardTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin38dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin38dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding5dp"
            android:id="@+id/adTryAgain"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My Alert Dialog class.

```
public class AlertDialogClass extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView tryAgainButton ;
    private AlertDialogClickInterface clickInterface ;


    public AlertDialogClass(AlertDialogClickInterface clickInterface) {
        this.clickInterface = clickInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);
        tryAgainButton = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.adTryAgain);
        tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(layout);

        return dialog;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.adTryAgain){
            clickInterface.OnAlertButtonClicked();
        }

    }

    public interface AlertDialogClickInterface {
        void OnAlertButtonClicked();
    }

}
```

Fragment from where i want to show the alert dialog.

```
try {

    if (CheckConnection.isConnected())
        getDataFromViewModel();

    else {

        AlertDialogClass dialogClass = new AlertDialogClass( this);
        dialogClass.show(getChildFragmentManager(),dialogClass.getTag());
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Expected layout should be like this:

[image: Layout I created for alert builder]

But the actual output is like this:

[image: original output]

Here is the styles that I have used in text views

```
<style name="CardTextView" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorWhite1</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize18</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-smallcaps</item>
</style>

<style name="CardTextViewSmall" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorWhite2</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize14</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-smallcaps</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the styles that i have used for text views. And to make sure if style file are causing the problem or not i have removed all the style files from layout and try to run it. But it still does not work, shows the same output mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change from:

```
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(layout);
```

To this:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.setContentView(layout);
```

**Added 1**

`dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

this one uses to keep the background around your dialog transparent.

---

`dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

And this one keeps your dialog height just like what it has set in the XML file.

Comment: After making the changes as you said it shows the expected layout now.As you said, `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` method should have make sure that my alert takes only that much space mentioned inside layout file.But the alert dialog is still taking the the whole screen. I have tried to tweak with that setLaout() method but it does't seem to work. Any suggestions how to fix alert dialog from taking the whole screen?

Comment: @samriddha as you can see in my code, the Dialog replace the whole windows so we have no other way to take only space inside the layout file.

Comment: If you want to be able to click outside the dialog you have to setFlags FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH  for dialog's windows. By use this one:
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH  );

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I have solved the height issue by changing the parent class of my custom dialog class from DialogFragment to Dialog.After that adding below line does the trick:`getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` Thanks again mate.

Comment: I am happy to hear that!